# how to get content of value from CURL with php

Tags: php, html, regex, curl, md5

I'm trying an example using curl with an external website, so I can post a password and have it automatically transformed to md5. The code below is working fine:

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html");
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"md5=security-dz.com");
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFERE,TRUE);
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);

$con = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The result is:

```
MD5 hash for security-dz.com is : a4f90d17ccde2c836d4264709749751b
```

How I can get only this hash value `a4f90d17ccde2c836d4264709749751b` with regex in a blank page? I don't want to see the whole page, I only want to get the hash in a blank page. I tried explode but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You have to look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: yes i know but this is only an example i want to program other tools that's why i asked this question to get a clear idea

Comment: Please don't use the PHP short tag `<?` but rather use `<?php`. `<?` is a fast-lane to have your projects not work on other servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match an MD5 in your cURL results and put it in a variable:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html");
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"md5=security-dz.com");
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);

$con = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(preg_match('/[0-9a-f]{32}/', $con, $matches)){
   $md5 = $matches[0];
}

echo "MD5 is: ".$md5;

?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 didn't work bro, can you writte for me the whole code please

Comment: I've just edited it.. try again now? If it still doesn't work, print out "$con".. is it definitely returning data containing an MD5?